# Is there any way I could change the order of which Apache VirtualHosts load first?

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm using a wildcard subdomain to manage most of my requests but I'm running into an issue of getting one of my subdomains (let's say, wiki.domain.com) to load first.

I understand that loading this inside an httpd.conf or something would just be a case of resorting which VirtualHosts load first, but I am using a2ensite and sites-available to manage my domains (individual files for each domain), which, to my knowledge, means I have no real way of determining which domains are "loaded" first.

I am running Ubuntu Hardy.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe the order of loading is from the name of the configuration file in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.  so if you wanted one loaded first, you would name the file 000-wiki.domain.com (or a2ensite 000-wiki.domain.com)

Out of curiosity, why does the order matter for you?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, honestly. I'm just going about trying to figure out why the wildcard subdomain is shadowing the static subdomain and this just seemed like a logical conclusion.

Also, your suggestion solved this issue! Thanks!

(p.s. I'd vote you up but I don't have 15 rep yet :/ me = newbie)

Comment: The order matters because the first Vhost config has the highest priority and will be the one that gets used when others' names can't be matched: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: @bshea There's a comment from 4 years ago that already says this

Answer (score 36):

To check the currently loaded virtualHosts (and their load order):

```
httpd -S
```

on an Ubuntu OS you can also use the following:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: `sudo apache2ctl -S` -- unless you enjoy chasing down [false alarm](https://serverfault.com/a/416613/161152) error messages.

Answer (score 1):

(Because this question is related to system administration, it's better suited for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).)

Under Debian and Ubuntu's default configuration, sites are loaded in alphabetical order (using Apache's [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) directive), so you can change the order in which your sites load by changing their names.  (For example, the default site that Debian provides is actually named `000-default`, to make it very likely that it will load first.)